# Custom UINavigationBar with custom height causes the UIBarButtonItem's to be positioned wrong

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I created my own subclass of UINavigationBar in order to enable custom background that is taller than 44pxs.

I did it by overriding these two methods:

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self.backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.backgroundImage.size.width, self.backgroundImage.size.height)];
}

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size 
{
    CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width , self.backgroundImage.size.height);
    return newSize;
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: Custom bar with custom height]

Now, my problem as you can see is that all the UIBarButtonItem's (and the titleView) are placed at the bottom of the navigation bar.

I would like them to be pinned to the top of the bar (with some padding of course).
What to I need to override to achieve that?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

This is the solution that I used:

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
    {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 5;
        view.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

Does the trick for idle state, still have some weird behavior on push and pop items.

Comment: how did you solve this issue? could you post please!

Comment: Were you ever able to solve the push/pop issue?

Comment: @lti No unfortunately I haven't... I tried many things, even overriding addSubview: but it didn't seem to help... If you find a way, please post it here!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to override `layoutSubviews`: call `[super layoutSubviews]` inside and then reposition the items.

Comment: I already tried that to be honest, and it is almost working:
On idle state the buttons are in place, but while animating push and pops of navigation items, the starting position for all the animated objects is still at the bottom of the Bar.
I even tried to override addSubview: but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

To solve the push/pop issue use setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment in sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation_background.png"];
    [self setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:-7 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width , img.size.height);
    return newSize;
}
```

Comment: Really nice, thanks for the "setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment"-tip!